# problems with the color syntax in spyder 3.2

Tags: spyder

I just upgrade my spyder software to the more recent version 3.2 and I have cosmetic problems:

1. I can't choose the color profiles of the console and the editor independently anymore. **How can I control the color syntax of my editor and console separately ?**
2. I can't change the color profiles of the variable and file explorers. **How can I control the color syntax of my explorers ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) My answers:

> How can I control the color syntax of my editor and console separately ?

It can't be done anymore, sorry. We decided to unify both color schemes to provide a better user experience.

> How can I control the color syntax of my explorers ?

There's no way to do that at the moment, but we're working to have a color scheme for the entire application in Spyder **4** (to be released in 2018).